# CRC8-Check in PHP

Tags: php, checksum, crc

How can I generate a CRC-8 checksum in PHP?

Comment: [pburggraf/CRC](https://github.com/pburggraf/CRC) library, released under MIT license by [Philip Burggraf](https://github.com/pburggraf)

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be CRC8?

On PHP.net there is an really simple implementation of [CRC16](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php#86628) and a native version of [CRC32](http://php.net/crc32).

If it does have to be CRC8 I would recommend coding something from the pseudo code on the wikipedia page Marius pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function crcnifull ($dato, $byte)
{
  static $PolyFull=0x8c;

  for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++)
  {
    $x=$byte&1;
    $byte>>=1;
    if ($dato&1) $byte|=0x80;
    if ($x) $byte^=$PolyFull;
    $dato>>=1;
  }
  return $byte;
}

function crc8 (array $ar,$n=false)
{
  if ($n===false) $n=count($ar);
  $crcbyte=0;
  for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) $crcbyte=crcnifull($ar[$i], $crcbyte);
  return $crcbyte;
}
```

To use this function for a binary string you have to convert the binary string to an array first. That can be achieved like this:

```
function sbin2ar($sbin)
{
  $ar=array();
  $ll=strlen($sbin);
  for ($i=0; $i<$ll; $i++) $ar[]=ord(substr($sbin,$i,1));
  return $ar;
}
```

Example how to use the whole thing:

```
$crc8=crc8(sbin2ar($packet));
```

Comment: Bob, your code does not work for the "D$1I 11/14/2006 18:15:00 1634146 3772376 3772344 3772312 3772294 1*" string. Following your calculations, the crc8 calculations for that example give as result 28, when it should give 57. I hope you're still following this thread. Can you check this out, please?

Comment: I think Bob has just gotten his code [from Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qypDLF5W) without even adding a reference, so I doubt it will be fixed.

Comment: @PabloValls it should give 67, I think

Answer (score 0):

In a development we need to implement this functionality and we transfer the code from another programming language to PHP:

```php
class CRC8 {

    public $crc8Table = [
        0x00, 0x07, 0x0E, 0x09, 0x1C, 0x1B, 0x12, 0x15,
        0x38, 0x3F, 0x36, 0x31, 0x24, 0x23, 0x2A, 0x2D,
        0x70, 0x77, 0x7E, 0x79, 0x6C, 0x6B, 0x62, 0x65,
        0x48, 0x4F, 0x46, 0x41, 0x54, 0x53, 0x5A, 0x5D,
        0xE0, 0xE7, 0xEE, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xF2, 0xF5,
        0xD8, 0xDF, 0xD6, 0xD1, 0xC4, 0xC3, 0xCA, 0xCD,
        0x90, 0x97, 0x9E, 0x99, 0x8C, 0x8B, 0x82, 0x85,
        0xA8, 0xAF, 0xA6, 0xA1, 0xB4, 0xB3, 0xBA, 0xBD,
        0xC7, 0xC0, 0xC9, 0xCE, 0xDB, 0xDC, 0xD5, 0xD2,
        0xFF, 0xF8, 0xF1, 0xF6, 0xE3, 0xE4, 0xED, 0xEA,
        0xB7, 0xB0, 0xB9, 0xBE, 0xAB, 0xAC, 0xA5, 0xA2,
        0x8F, 0x88, 0x81, 0x86, 0x93, 0x94, 0x9D, 0x9A,
        0x27, 0x20, 0x29, 0x2E, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x35, 0x32,
        0x1F, 0x18, 0x11, 0x16, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0D, 0x0A,
        0x57, 0x50, 0x59, 0x5E, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x45, 0x42,
        0x6F, 0x68, 0x61, 0x66, 0x73, 0x74, 0x7D, 0x7A,
        0x89, 0x8E, 0x87, 0x80, 0x95, 0x92, 0x9B, 0x9C,
        0xB1, 0xB6, 0xBF, 0xB8, 0xAD, 0xAA, 0xA3, 0xA4,
        0xF9, 0xFE, 0xF7, 0xF0, 0xE5, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0xEC,
        0xC1, 0xC6, 0xCF, 0xC8, 0xDD, 0xDA, 0xD3, 0xD4,
        0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x60, 0x75, 0x72, 0x7B, 0x7C,
        0x51, 0x56, 0x5F, 0x58, 0x4D, 0x4A, 0x43, 0x44,
        0x19, 0x1E, 0x17, 0x10, 0x05, 0x02, 0x0B, 0x0C,
        0x21, 0x26, 0x2F, 0x28, 0x3D, 0x3A, 0x33, 0x34,
        0x4E, 0x49, 0x40, 0x47, 0x52, 0x55, 0x5C, 0x5B,
        0x76, 0x71, 0x78, 0x7F, 0x6A, 0x6D, 0x64, 0x63,
        0x3E, 0x39, 0x30, 0x37, 0x22, 0x25, 0x2C, 0x2B,
        0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x0F, 0x1A, 0x1D, 0x14, 0x13,
        0xAE, 0xA9, 0xA0, 0xA7, 0xB2, 0xB5, 0xBC, 0xBB,
        0x96, 0x91, 0x98, 0x9F, 0x8A, 0x8D, 0x84, 0x83,
        0xDE, 0xD9, 0xD0, 0xD7, 0xC2, 0xC5, 0xCC, 0xCB,
        0xE6, 0xE1, 0xE8, 0xEF, 0xFA, 0xFD, 0xF4, 0xF3
    ];

    public function getCRC8($input)
    {
        $byteArray = unpack('C*', $input);
        $len = count($byteArray);
        $crc = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
            $crc = $this->crc8Table[($crc ^ $byteArray[$i]) & 0xff];
        }
        return $crc & 0xff;
    }

}
```